# Ms Access data still in database after Uninstall

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, inno-setup

I have an App that was designed with `Vb.Net 2010` and it uses `Ms Access 2007` for its database.

The program executes fine but I found something funny when I uninstalled the program and re-installed it, data that I entered before I uninstalled are still in the new database even when the re-install action copies a fresh database to the location. I checked to see if the uninstall action deletes the database on uninstall, and I found that it deletes everything including all folders. I don't know if it is somehow caching somewhere or something.

I am using Inno Setup Compiler for my install script, and there are no instructions to copy the database anywhere else apart from the default location.

My `connectionString` in the app points to the `App Folder` where the database is located.

I have checked online and I got unrelated result (maybe I don't know the correct keyword to search for).

Please, can someone help explain what is happening and possible solution?

I need help, thanks.

Comment: it wouldn't make sense. clearly the connectionstring is pointing to a different database as if the database was removed and you tried to connect, it would throw an error.

Comment: No errors, I am talking about a fresh install. A freshly installed app still shows data from a supposed uninstalled database.

Comment: Like @Ahmed Ilyas I wonder if it is using the DB you believe. If you open the DB after install, with another tool e.g. Excel and ODBC if Access not installed, and alter the data do you see thr altered data in your app?

Comment: After uninstalling can you see a copy of the database file somewhere under `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files` ?

Comment: How are you instructing InnoSetup to copy the fresh database file?  Are you explicitly deleting the database during Uninstall? Please post the `[Files]` entry for the database.

Comment: @Karl I just opened the said database in the expected and I could not find data in it, although data is showing in my app.

Comment: @GordThompson It is using the database in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files`, why is this when my `connectionsting` point else where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are being fooled by [User Account Control (UAC) virtualization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee732424%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). You have apparently stored your database file under %ProgramFiles% and users do not have read/write access to those folders, so Windows makes a copy of the file in a subfolder of

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files

and redirects read/write operations to that copy.

When you uninstall your application the installer probably runs under elevated privileges (via the UAC prompt) and removes the original copy of the database file (in %ProgramFiles%) but the virtualized copy remains. Then when you reinstall (again, with elevated privileges) the original file gets copied back into %ProgramFiles% but the (modified) virtualized copy is already in place so you see the old data from before.

Moral: If your application needs to make modifications to the database file do NOT store it along with your application files. Have your installer put it somewhere where users normally have read/write access, e.g., under %USERPROFILE% for individual users, or %PUBLIC% for multiple users on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination,  it helped a lot. Is there no way I can give my app read/write permission to use the database stored in my app folder under `Program Files`?  Am thinking if I put it under `USER PROFILE`, the user can mistakenly delete them at any point in time thinking it is some temporary files.

Comment: If your installer is running under elevated privileges then it could almost certainly alter the permissions on the subfolder of %ProgramFiles% where your application resides, but that would generally be considered a "Bad Thing" to do. Somewhat less "Bad" would be to put the database file in a subfolder of %ProgramData% and tweak the permissions on that folder. (It's still a "system folder", but it's generally not considered as sensitive as %ProgramFiles% and it's hidden by default.)

Comment: Thanks,  I placed decided to copy the database to `% USER PROFILE/APPDATA/LOCAL/FOLDER%`